# Having trouble linking JS to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting my JavaScript to work on my site. Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jurx/1/) of what I am trying to use. It works fine here but not at all on my site. Here is how I am linking the JS on my site:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="main_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="main_JS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: The JQuery file is saved in the same location as my site.

Comment: Any errors in DEV console?

Comment: Is your jQuery within a document.ready call?

Comment: Are those JS files actually located in the same directory as the HTML file linking them?  And, what type of web server are you using?

Comment: Yes. That <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
can't be saved without a type tag.

Comment: Yes the files are saved in the same directory.

Comment: Modify the tag to say <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: With the modification when I load the page the JavaScript still won't play. Do I need to point to another JS file like from Google?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping all of your JavaScript code in jQuery's document ready method?

```
$(function(){
    var timer;
    var light = 1;

    colorarray = new Array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'green', 'chocolate', 'cyan');

    function timedCount()
    {
      timer = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},800);
      $(".interactiveBox div:nth-child("+ light +")").css('background-color', colorarray[light]);
      light = light + 1;
      if(light>8)
      {
            light = 1;
            $('.interactiveBox div').css( 'background-color', 'white');
       }
   }

    $('.start').click(function(){
        timedCount();
    });

   $('.stop').click(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
   });

});
```

Also, make sure you include the jQuery.js file before the jQuery-ui.js file.  Above this line:

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

The file should look like:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="main_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- NEED TO INCLUDE THE MAIN JQUERY.JS HERE -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- /NEED TO INCLUDE THE MAIN JQUERY.JS HERE -->
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="main_JS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: timer = setTimeout(timedCount,800); *

Comment: I added the wrap, added the "type="text/javascript", and put the main_JS file first but when I run the page the JavaScript still won't play. Do I need to point to another JS file like from Google?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to rename the main_JS file so that there wasn't an extra js in the name.

now this is how I have it setup and it runs just fine.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="main_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error you're getting, try changing the jQuery link to this...

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

1. jQuery UI requires the main JQuery library (make sure to download it and link to the appropriate version you've downloaded).
2. Make sure to include the type declaration in your script tags, so the debugger doesn't complain.

Comment: Unnecessary in HTML5.

Comment: Irrelevant. They're getting an error saying that "jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js can't be saved without a type tag".  So, add the type tag.

Comment: I changed it and the JavaScript still isn't playing when the page is run.

Comment: You can either download the main jQuery library (from here http://jquery.com/), or link to it here...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>